# Search delimited text file for two values then output first parameter of the line

Tags: php, text, csv

I have the following script:

```
<?php 
$search = $_REQUEST["search"]; 
$search2 = $_REQUEST['search2'];
// Read from file 
$lines = file('archive.txt'); 
echo"<html><head><title>SEARCH RESULTS FOR: $search</title></head><body>";
foreach($lines as $line) 
{ 
// Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does 
if(stristr($line,$search) && stristr($line,$search2))  // case insensitive
    echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>"; 
} 
?>
</body></html>
```

At the moment you can search for two variables and it will output the entire line. Please can you help me just to output the first art of the line (which is pipe delimited)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this inside your foreach loop...

```
if(stristr($line,$search) && stristr($line,$search2)) { // case insensitive
    $line = explode("|", $line);
    $line = $line[0];
    echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>"; 
}
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, "<p>{$line</p>" would work better. Font and delimiting could then be added via CSS (the font tag being deprecated).

Comment: Thanks for this joshwa but it comes up with an error saying there is an unexpected $end.

Comment: If you comment out the echo do you still get the error?